# Insert characters at multiple positions in a dataframe column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a table with a lot of rows, and i need to change all the first " " space for "h" the second space for "m" and add at last char "s"

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'RA' : ['11 50 10.4747', "11 50 10.2641","11 50 10.0534", "11 50 09.8428"],'DEC':["+26 01 09.559","+26 01 10.770", "+26 01 11.980","+26 01 13.191"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
for i in range(len(df)):
    RA = df['RA'][i]
    RA = str.replace(RA, " ", "h", 1)
    RA = str.replace(RA, " ", "m", 1)
    RA += "s"
    df['RA'][i] = RA
    DEC = df['DEC'][i]
    DEC = str.replace(DEC, " ", "d", 1)
    DEC = str.replace(DEC, " ", "m", 1)
    DEC += "s"
    df['DEC'][i] = DEC
```

I have made this code, but for my use is getting a slow.
With this code I change my data frame from:

```
     DEC             RA
+26 01 09.559  11 50 10.4747 
+26 01 10.770  11 50 10.2641  
+26 01 11.980  11 50 10.0534 
+26 01 13.191  11 50 09.8428
```

To This:

```
         DEC              RA
0  +26d01m09.559s  11h50m10.4747s
1  +26d01m10.770s  11h50m10.2641s
2  +26d01m11.980s  11h50m10.0534s
3  +26d01m13.191s  11h50m09.8428s
```

Is there any function that i can do this?
I tried using df.replace, but it replaces all " " in the table...

thanks for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a function to handle splitting and recombination. You may use `str.split`, followed by some super simple string concatenation, respectively.

```
def split_combine(v, letters=list('dms')):
    v = v.str.split(expand=True)
    return (
       v[0] + letters[0] 
     + v[1] + letters[1] 
     + v[2] + letters[2]
    )
```

Now, call it with your appropriate parameters.

```
df['DEC'] = split_combine(df.DEC, list('dms'))
df['RA'] = split_combine(df.RA, list('hms'))

df
              DEC              RA
0  +26d01m09.559s  11h50m10.4747s
1  +26d01m10.770s  11h50m10.2641s
2  +26d01m11.980s  11h50m10.0534s
3  +26d01m13.191s  11h50m09.8428s
```

Comment: This is smart :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 d['DEC'] = d['DEC'].str.replace(' ','d',1).str.replace(' ','m',1) + 's'
 d['RA'] = d['RA'].str.replace(' ','h',1).str.replace(' ','m',1) + 's'
```

or define a function:

```
def repl(series, replace_letters):
    return series.str.replace(' ',replace_letters[0],1).str.replace(' ',replace_letters[1],1) + replace_letters[2]
```

and call function on both columns:

```
d['DEC'] = repl(d['DEC'],'dms')
d['RA'] = repl(d['RA'],'hms')
```

both results in

```
           DEC           RA
0   +26d01m09.559s  11h50m10.4747s
1   +26d01m10.770s  11h50m10.2641s
2   +26d01m11.980s  11h50m10.0534s
3   +26d01m13.191s  11h50m09.8428s
```

Comment: The first DEC column needs `d`, not `h`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df['RA'] = df['RA'].str.split(' ').str[0] + 'h' +  df['RA'].str.split(' ').str[1] + 'm' + df['RA'].str.split(' ').str[2]+ 's'
df['DEC'] = df['DEC'].str.split(' ').str[0] + 'd' +  df['DEC'].str.split(' ').str[1] + 'm' + df['DEC'].str.split(' ').str[2]+ 's'
```

Output:

```
              DEC              RA
0  +26d01m09.559s  11h50m10.4747s
1  +26d01m10.770s  11h50m10.2641s
2  +26d01m11.980s  11h50m10.0534s
3  +26d01m13.191s  11h50m09.8428s
```